# Callback Method in Datetime Picker in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using this datetime picker :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datetimepicker

Official document link :- https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-datetimepicker/#/datetimepicker.

I'm getting the date in callback method. 
http://cuppalabs.github.io/components/datepicker/#Callback-Methods

```js
onDateSelect($event): void {
  console.log($event);
}
```

In my component.html file.

```html
<angular2-date-picker 
  (onDateSelect)="onDateSelect($event)" 
  [(ngModel)]="date" 
  [settings]="{
    bigBanner: true,
    timePicker: true,
    format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a'
   }">
</angular2-date-picker>
```

But i'm getting only this value in it's callback events.

```
Tue Apr 24 2018 17:01:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

So, I'm confused how can I get and set values in it because it's in a form so how I can use this callback function in getting and setting value.

Comment: try out ngModelChange

Comment: @PranayRana. I got this error `'ngModelChange' since it isn't a known property of 'angular2-date-picker'.` May be they are binding through ngModel only.

Comment: you tried in like this `(ngModelChange) = function` ?

Comment: I have never user ngModelChange I'm checking how to use it on internet just give me 5 minutes.

Comment: it just same way as you used `(onDateSelect)`, its just for handling change event...(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"

Comment: Oh. Great got it. Thank you for your help. Now, If I'm chanding any thing in datetime picker i'm getting callback. 
Now I'm getting changed date. And my date format is `Tue Apr 24 2018 17:01:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
`. So I have to just convert this format to `dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm`. Please add your comment as a answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"`  and handle event it will resolve issue.

so you code will be somewhat as below

```
<angular2-date-picker (ngModelChange)="onDateSelect($event)" ..rest of code
```